# C++. Classe genérica recebendo função lambda e struct

Tags: c++, expressões-lambda, c++11

Caros,

estou tentando fazer algumas coisas em C++, mas ainda estou começando tanto na linguagem quanto no paradigma funcional. O que preciso é inserir uma função `lambda` num `pair`. O primeiro membro do `pair` será um objeto `struct`, e o segundo, a função lambda. A minha função lambda recebe como parâmetros uma `struct` e um `vector<string>` e retorna uma `string`, algo como:

```
auto lambda = [](struct &s, vector<string> &v){
    return (s.atributo + " " + v[0]);
};
```

Nesse caso, o `pair` seria algo como:

```
pair<struct, funcao_lambda> par;
```

Já me deparei com muitos erros de tipo (quando tentava inserir a função lambda num `map`), e na busca por uma solução, encontrei algo que possa resolver: uma classe genérica que embrulhe as funções lambdas e que tenha um método de execução da função lambda. Encontrei um exemplo de classe genérica para isso, mas pelo meu desconhecimento da linguagem, não sei como alterá-la para que aceite funções lambdas com parâmetros (sem captura):

```
class T {
private:
    double (*expression)();
public:
    T(double (*exp)()) : expression(exp) {}
    double execute() {
        return this->expression();
    }
};

int main() {
    T t([]()->double {return 1+1;});
    double val = t.execute(); // val = 2
    return 0;
}
```

Além de alterar os tipos `double` para `string`, o que mais preciso alterar na classe para que ela receba funções lambda com parâmetros (sem captura, somente parâmetros)? A ideia é que os tipos T sejam criados nessa forma:

```
T t([](struct &s, vector<string> &v) -> string {
     return (s.atributo + " " + v[0]);
});
```

E sejam executados nessa forma:

```
string texto = t.execute(struct, vector<string>);
```

Isso é possível? E mais importante, vai ser possível inserir esse tipo T no `pair`?

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não gostei muito dessa solução com o uso de uma classe e de um ponteiro para uma função. Ela me parece difícil de ler e, além do mais, o uso de ponteiros para função em C++11 (e posteriores) é algo um pouco antiquado.

Se a sua intenção é só inserir uma expressão lambda em um `std::pair` ou em um `std::map`, o uso de uma instância da classe `std::function` resolveria os seus problemas de tipo. Confira o seguinte código:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

struct A{
    std::string atributo;

    //sobrecarga do operador<
    //sem isso um objeto da struct A não pode ser chave de um std::map
    bool operator<(const A &other) const {
        return (atributo < other.atributo);
    }
};

int main() {

    //cria a expressão lambda
    std::function<std::string(A&, std::vector<std::string>&)> lambda = 
        [](A& s, std::vector<std::string> &v)->std::string {
        return (s.atributo + " " + v[0]);
    };

    // cria uma instância de A
    A s;
    s.atributo = "Waiting for";

    //cria um std::vector 
    std::vector<std::string> v{ "Godot", "Hamlet" };

    //insere a expressão lambda e o vetor dentro de um std::pair 
    std::pair<A, std::function<std::string(A&, std::vector<std::string>&)>> myPair =
    { s, lambda };

    //testa o par 
    std::cout << myPair.second(myPair.first, v) << "\n";

    //insere o par em um std::map
    std::map<A, std::function<std::string(A&, std::vector<std::string>&)>> myMap;
    myMap.insert(myPair);

    //testa o map
    std::cout << myMap[s](s, v);

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

/*saída:
Waiting for Godot
Waiting for Godot
*/
```

EDIT: Eu fiz a solução com a classe que você apresentou, se você quiser comparar ambas as soluções segue o código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct A {
    std::string atributo;

    //sobrecarga do operador<
    //sem isso um objeto da struct A não pode ser chave de um std::map
    bool operator<(const A &other) const {
        return (atributo < other.atributo);
    }
};

//mudei o nome da classe para B, pois T confunde com template.
class B {
private:
    std::string(*expression)(A &s, std::vector<std::string>& v);
public:
    B(std::string(*exp)(A &s, std::vector<std::string>& v)) : expression(exp) {}
    std::string execute(A &s, std::vector<std::string>& v) {
        return this->expression(s, v);
    }
};

int main() {

    // cria uma instância de A
    A a;
    a.atributo = "Waiting for";

    //cria uma instância de B
    B b([](A& s, std::vector<std::string> &v)->std::string {
        return s.atributo + " " + v[0]; });

    //cria um std::vector
    std::vector<std::string> v{ "Godot", "Hamlet" };

    //criar std::pair
    std::pair<A, B> myPair = { a, b };

    //testa std::pair
    std::cout << myPair.second.execute(myPair.first, v) << '\n';    

    //cria std::map e insere myPair
    std::map<A, B> myMap;
    myMap.insert(myPair);

    //testa std::map
    std::cout << myMap.at(a).execute(a, v) << '\n';

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Primeiramente, muito obrigado pela ajuda! Muito precisa! Está claro que eu preciso estudar C++ bastante... No seu exemplo, um dos atributos da função lambda é o primeiro membro do pair, e é exatamente isso que eu preciso. Acredito que essa solução vai resolver o meu problema.

E vou voltar a usar o map, pois nele vou referenciar que pair de struct e função lambda devo usar posteriormente. Mas ainda tenho algumas dúvidas, que vou colocar no próximo comentário por conta de espaço :)

Comment: 1. A chave do map será uma string, e não a struct como no seu exemplo, pois quando eu for buscar o pair, vou comparar com uma string. Então basta que eu mude a criação do map para "map<string, B> myMap;"? E como seria a inserção no myMap?

2. No fim de tudo, eu preciso da string que a função lambda retorna, pois ela vai processar atributos da struct e outros que vou passar pelo vector. Pra eu obter essa string de retorno da função lambda, como seria? Algo como "string txt1 = myMap.at("txt2").execute(myPair.first, v);"? 

Essa string final txt1 é o que preciso, depois de toda essa batalha!

Comment: Respondendo suas perguntas: 1) Sim, se você precisa de uma chave string, altere para string; 2) Existem diferentes métodos para inserção em um `map`, eu usei `insert()`, passando um `pair` como parâmetro, mas isso é algo que você precisará estudar; 3)  a função retorna uma `string`, então, sim, você pode armazenar o valor de retorno em uma variável do tipo `string`.

Comment: @DanielElias, marque a resposta como "aceita", ela está muito boa

Comment: Sim, está excelente! Me esqueci disso, já estou marcando. Estou resolvendo alguns outros problemas aqui.